# TensorFlow: Is there a way to locate the filenames of images encoded into TFRecord files?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am wondering if the filename information of the image encoded could be encoded into a TFRecord file while creating the tfrecord files, and if so, how could this information be decoded back? When decoded, is the filename a Tensor object?

Comment: A TFRecord is just a dictionary of tensors. So yes, all the values inside are tensors. When creating the TFRecord you have to explicitly set one of the fields to be the name of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like fabrizioM said, you have to store the sources in the tfrecords file if you want to use them. [Here is an example](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/ML/tf-image-loading):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Example for reading and writing tfrecords."""

import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc


def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def write_images(filenames=['Aurelia-aurita-3.jpg'],
                 labels=[0],
                 tf_records_filename="example.tfrecords"):
    """
    Write images to tfrecords file.

    Parameters
    ----------
    filenames : list of strings
        List containing the paths to image files.
    labels : list of integers
    tf_records_filename : string
        Where the file gets stored
    """
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    my_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value)

    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)

        # Start populating the filename queue.
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tf_records_filename)
        for i in range(len(filenames)):
            image = my_img.eval()  # image is an image tensor

            image_raw = image.tostring()
            rows = image.shape[0]
            cols = image.shape[1]

            if np.ndim(image) == 3:
                depth = image.shape[2]
            else:
                depth = 1

            example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'height': _int64_feature(rows),
                'width': _int64_feature(cols),
                'depth': _int64_feature(depth),
                'label': _int64_feature(labels[i]),
                'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw),
                'src': _bytes_feature(filenames[i])}))
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)


def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    """Read and decode them from filename_queue."""
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
        features={
            'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'src': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        })
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
    height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)
    depth = tf.cast(features['depth'], tf.int32)
    # fn = tf.cast(features['filename'], tf.str)
    return image, label, height, width, depth, features['src']


def get_all_records(record_filename):
    """Get all records from record_filename."""
    records = []
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        fn_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([record_filename])
        image, label, height, width, depth, src = read_and_decode(fn_queue)
        image = tf.reshape(image, tf.stack([height, width, 3]))
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init_op)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        nr_of_images = 1
        for i in range(nr_of_images):
            example, label, src = sess.run([image, label, src])
            img = Image.fromarray(example, 'RGB')
            records.append({'image': img, 'label': label,
                            'src': src})
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
    return records

write_images()
records = get_all_records('example.tfrecords')
print(records[0]['src'])
scipy.misc.imshow(records[0]['image'])
```