# How can I extract the names of images after they have been converted to TFRecords?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

I need to synchronize my neural network training with two different inputs. One is image data in the form of tfrecords, and the other is tabular data which with some information on each image.

The problem is I don't know how I can connect the two because the jpegs are converted to uninterpretable tfrecords and shuffled before they are feed to the network. I was wondering how I can get the filenames of the image each record was made from.

The records are made by running the following:

`python build_image_data.py --directory='../sorted_tiles/' --output_directory='../trainingshards/' --train_shards=4096  --validation_shards=0 --num_threads=16`

--directory is the location of the images. The images are stored in two subdirectories and the names of the subdirectories are the labels of the images.

Below is the source code for build_image_data.py

```
Below is the script that each record is made from:

# Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
"""Converts image data to TFRecords file format with Example protos.

The image data set is expected to reside in JPEG files located in the
following directory structure.

  data_dir/label_0/image0.jpeg
  data_dir/label_0/image1.jpg
  ...
  data_dir/label_1/weird-image.jpeg
  data_dir/label_1/my-image.jpeg
  ...

where the sub-directory is the unique label associated with these images.

This TensorFlow script converts the training and evaluation data into
a sharded data set consisting of TFRecord files

  train_directory/train-00000-of-01024
  train_directory/train-00001-of-01024
  ...
  train_directory/train-01023-of-01024

and

  validation_directory/validation-00000-of-00128
  validation_directory/validation-00001-of-00128
  ...
  validation_directory/validation-00127-of-00128

where we have selected 1024 and 128 shards for each data set. Each record
within the TFRecord file is a serialized Example proto. The Example proto
contains the following fields:

  image/encoded: string containing JPEG encoded image in RGB colorspace
  image/height: integer, image height in pixels
  image/width: integer, image width in pixels
  image/colorspace: string, specifying the colorspace, always 'RGB'
  image/channels: integer, specifying the number of channels, always 3
  image/format: string, specifying the format, always 'JPEG'

  image/filename: string containing the basename of the image file
            e.g. 'n01440764_10026.JPEG' or 'ILSVRC2012_val_00000293.JPEG'
  image/class/label: integer specifying the index in a classification layer.
    The label ranges from [0, num_labels] where 0 is unused and left as
    the background class.
  image/class/text: string specifying the human-readable version of the label
    e.g. 'dog'

If your data set involves bounding boxes, please look at build_imagenet_data.py.
"""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from datetime import datetime
import os
import random
import sys
import threading

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('train_directory', '/tmp/',
                           'Training data directory')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('validation_directory', '/tmp/',
                           'Validation data directory')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('output_directory', '/tmp/',
                           'Output data directory')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('train_shards', 2,
                            'Number of shards in training TFRecord files.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('validation_shards', 2,
                            'Number of shards in validation TFRecord files.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_threads', 2,
                            'Number of threads to preprocess the images.')

# The labels file contains a list of valid labels are held in this file.
# Assumes that the file contains entries as such:
#   dog
#   cat
#   flower
# where each line corresponds to a label. We map each label contained in
# the file to an integer corresponding to the line number starting from 0.
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('labels_file', '', 'Labels file')


FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS


def _int64_feature(value):
  """Wrapper for inserting int64 features into Example proto."""
  if not isinstance(value, list):
    value = [value]
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))


def _bytes_feature(value):
  """Wrapper for inserting bytes features into Example proto."""
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def _convert_to_example(filename, image_buffer, label, text, height, width):
  """Build an Example proto for an example.

  Args:
    filename: string, path to an image file, e.g., '/path/to/example.JPG'
    image_buffer: string, JPEG encoding of RGB image
    label: integer, identifier for the ground truth for the network
    text: string, unique human-readable, e.g. 'dog'
    height: integer, image height in pixels
    width: integer, image width in pixels
  Returns:
    Example proto
  """

  colorspace = 'RGB'
  channels = 3
  image_format = 'JPEG'

  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'image/height': _int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': _int64_feature(width),
      'image/colorspace': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(colorspace)),
      'image/channels': _int64_feature(channels),
      'image/class/label': _int64_feature(label),
      'image/class/text': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(text)),
      'image/format': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(image_format)),
      'image/filename': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(os.path.basename(filename))),
      'image/encoded': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(image_buffer))}))
  return example


class ImageCoder(object):
  """Helper class that provides TensorFlow image coding utilities."""

  def __init__(self):
    # Create a single Session to run all image coding calls.
    self._sess = tf.Session()

    # Initializes function that converts PNG to JPEG data.
    self._png_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(self._png_data, channels=3)
    self._png_to_jpeg = tf.image.encode_jpeg(image, format='rgb', quality=100)

    # Initializes function that decodes RGB JPEG data.
    self._decode_jpeg_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)
    self._decode_jpeg = tf.image.decode_jpeg(self._decode_jpeg_data, channels=3)

  def png_to_jpeg(self, image_data):
    return self._sess.run(self._png_to_jpeg,
                          feed_dict={self._png_data: image_data})

  def decode_jpeg(self, image_data):
    image = self._sess.run(self._decode_jpeg,
                           feed_dict={self._decode_jpeg_data: image_data})
    assert len(image.shape) == 3
    assert image.shape[2] == 3
    return image


def _is_png(filename):
  """Determine if a file contains a PNG format image.

  Args:
    filename: string, path of the image file.

  Returns:
    boolean indicating if the image is a PNG.
  """
  return '.png' in filename


def _process_image(filename, coder):
  """Process a single image file.

  Args:
    filename: string, path to an image file e.g., '/path/to/example.JPG'.
    coder: instance of ImageCoder to provide TensorFlow image coding utils.
  Returns:
    image_buffer: string, JPEG encoding of RGB image.
    height: integer, image height in pixels.
    width: integer, image width in pixels.
  """
  # Read the image file.
  with tf.gfile.FastGFile(filename, 'r') as f:
    image_data = f.read()

  # Convert any PNG to JPEG's for consistency.
  if _is_png(filename):
    print('Converting PNG to JPEG for %s' % filename)
    image_data = coder.png_to_jpeg(image_data)

  # Decode the RGB JPEG.
  image = coder.decode_jpeg(image_data)

  # Check that image converted to RGB
  assert len(image.shape) == 3
  height = image.shape[0]
  width = image.shape[1]
  assert image.shape[2] == 3

  return image_data, height, width


def _process_image_files_batch(coder, thread_index, ranges, name, filenames,
                               texts, labels, num_shards):
  """Processes and saves list of images as TFRecord in 1 thread.

  Args:
    coder: instance of ImageCoder to provide TensorFlow image coding utils.
    thread_index: integer, unique batch to run index is within [0, len(ranges)).
    ranges: list of pairs of integers specifying ranges of each batches to
      analyze in parallel.
    name: string, unique identifier specifying the data set
    filenames: list of strings; each string is a path to an image file
    texts: list of strings; each string is human readable, e.g. 'dog'
    labels: list of integer; each integer identifies the ground truth
    num_shards: integer number of shards for this data set.
  """
  # Each thread produces N shards where N = int(num_shards / num_threads).
  # For instance, if num_shards = 128, and the num_threads = 2, then the first
  # thread would produce shards [0, 64).
  num_threads = len(ranges)
  assert not num_shards % num_threads
  num_shards_per_batch = int(num_shards / num_threads)

  shard_ranges = np.linspace(ranges[thread_index][0],
                             ranges[thread_index][1],
                             num_shards_per_batch + 1).astype(int)
  num_files_in_thread = ranges[thread_index][1] - ranges[thread_index][0]

  counter = 0
  for s in range(num_shards_per_batch):
    # Generate a sharded version of the file name, e.g. 'train-00002-of-00010'
    shard = thread_index * num_shards_per_batch + s
    output_filename = '%s-%.5d-of-%.5d' % (name, shard, num_shards)
    output_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.output_directory, output_filename)
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_file)

    shard_counter = 0
    files_in_shard = np.arange(shard_ranges[s], shard_ranges[s + 1], dtype=int)
    for i in files_in_shard:
      filename = filenames[i]
      label = labels[i]
      text = texts[i]

      try:
        image_buffer, height, width = _process_image(filename, coder)
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('SKIPPED: Unexpected eror while decoding %s.' % filename)
        continue

      example = _convert_to_example(filename, image_buffer, label,
                                    text, height, width)
      writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
      shard_counter += 1
      counter += 1

      if not counter % 1000:
        print('%s [thread %d]: Processed %d of %d images in thread batch.' %
              (datetime.now(), thread_index, counter, num_files_in_thread))
        sys.stdout.flush()

    writer.close()
    print('%s [thread %d]: Wrote %d images to %s' %
          (datetime.now(), thread_index, shard_counter, output_file))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    shard_counter = 0
  print('%s [thread %d]: Wrote %d images to %d shards.' %
        (datetime.now(), thread_index, counter, num_files_in_thread))
  sys.stdout.flush()


def _process_image_files(name, filenames, texts, labels, num_shards):
  """Process and save list of images as TFRecord of Example protos.

  Args:
    name: string, unique identifier specifying the data set
    filenames: list of strings; each string is a path to an image file
    texts: list of strings; each string is human readable, e.g. 'dog'
    labels: list of integer; each integer identifies the ground truth
    num_shards: integer number of shards for this data set.
  """
  assert len(filenames) == len(texts)
  assert len(filenames) == len(labels)

  # Break all images into batches with a [ranges[i][0], ranges[i][1]].
  spacing = np.linspace(0, len(filenames), FLAGS.num_threads + 1).astype(np.int)
  ranges = []
  for i in range(len(spacing) - 1):
    ranges.append([spacing[i], spacing[i + 1]])

  # Launch a thread for each batch.
  print('Launching %d threads for spacings: %s' % (FLAGS.num_threads, ranges))
  sys.stdout.flush()

  # Create a mechanism for monitoring when all threads are finished.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

  # Create a generic TensorFlow-based utility for converting all image codings.
  coder = ImageCoder()

  threads = []
  for thread_index in range(len(ranges)):
    args = (coder, thread_index, ranges, name, filenames,
            texts, labels, num_shards)
    t = threading.Thread(target=_process_image_files_batch, args=args)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

  # Wait for all the threads to terminate.
  coord.join(threads)
  print('%s: Finished writing all %d images in data set.' %
        (datetime.now(), len(filenames)))
  sys.stdout.flush()


def _find_image_files(data_dir, labels_file):
  """Build a list of all images files and labels in the data set.

  Args:
    data_dir: string, path to the root directory of images.

      Assumes that the image data set resides in JPEG files located in
      the following directory structure.

        data_dir/dog/another-image.JPEG
        data_dir/dog/my-image.jpg

      where 'dog' is the label associated with these images.

    labels_file: string, path to the labels file.

      The list of valid labels are held in this file. Assumes that the file
      contains entries as such:
        dog
        cat
        flower
      where each line corresponds to a label. We map each label contained in
      the file to an integer starting with the integer 0 corresponding to the
      label contained in the first line.

  Returns:
    filenames: list of strings; each string is a path to an image file.
    texts: list of strings; each string is the class, e.g. 'dog'
    labels: list of integer; each integer identifies the ground truth.
  """
  print('Determining list of input files and labels from %s.' % data_dir)
  unique_labels = [l.strip() for l in tf.gfile.FastGFile(
      labels_file, 'r').readlines()]

  labels = []
  filenames = []
  texts = []

  # Leave label index 0 empty as a background class.
  label_index = 1

  # Construct the list of JPEG files and labels.
  for text in unique_labels:
    jpeg_file_path = '%s/%s/*' % (data_dir, text)
    matching_files = tf.gfile.Glob(jpeg_file_path)

    labels.extend([label_index] * len(matching_files))
    texts.extend([text] * len(matching_files))
    filenames.extend(matching_files)

    if not label_index % 100:
      print('Finished finding files in %d of %d classes.' % (
          label_index, len(labels)))
    label_index += 1

  # Shuffle the ordering of all image files in order to guarantee
  # random ordering of the images with respect to label in the
  # saved TFRecord files. Make the randomization repeatable.
  shuffled_index = list(range(len(filenames)))
  random.seed(12345)
  random.shuffle(shuffled_index)

  filenames = [filenames[i] for i in shuffled_index]
  texts = [texts[i] for i in shuffled_index]
  labels = [labels[i] for i in shuffled_index]

  print('Found %d JPEG files across %d labels inside %s.' %
        (len(filenames), len(unique_labels), data_dir))
  return filenames, texts, labels


def _process_dataset(name, directory, num_shards, labels_file):
  """Process a complete data set and save it as a TFRecord.

  Args:
    name: string, unique identifier specifying the data set.
    directory: string, root path to the data set.
    num_shards: integer number of shards for this data set.
    labels_file: string, path to the labels file.
  """
  filenames, texts, labels = _find_image_files(directory, labels_file)
  _process_image_files(name, filenames, texts, labels, num_shards)


def main(unused_argv):
  assert not FLAGS.train_shards % FLAGS.num_threads, (
      'Please make the FLAGS.num_threads commensurate with FLAGS.train_shards')
  assert not FLAGS.validation_shards % FLAGS.num_threads, (
      'Please make the FLAGS.num_threads commensurate with '
      'FLAGS.validation_shards')
  print('Saving results to %s' % FLAGS.output_directory)

  # Run it!
  _process_dataset('validation', FLAGS.validation_directory,
                   FLAGS.validation_shards, FLAGS.labels_file)
  _process_dataset('train', FLAGS.train_directory,
                   FLAGS.train_shards, FLAGS.labels_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Comment: add the image names to a list,(just before making the tfrecords, so that you write after the shuffling) and write the list to a text file. So that, the order in which it is written in tf records, the text file will have the name list accordingly. Then where ever u want , u can read the text file with image names to do next steps.

Comment: That won't work because I need to shuffle the records before feeding it to the network. Also, I have about 5 million images so I'd like to avoid keeping around a giant text file I always need to read from

Comment: can this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444468/tensorflow-is-there-a-way-to-locate-the-filenames-of-images-encoded-into-tfreco

Comment: Sadly it does not. I made a new point for this question because i think I might have given the wrong context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383969/how-do-i-extract-the-values-from-these-tensors-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find the distribution of images so I created a small program to find filenames of images embedded in my tfrecords. In my case I wanted to see how many from every folder went in train, test, val. The code is sort of self explanatory, but let me know.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category = FutureWarning)  #tf 1.14 and np 1.17 are clashing: temporary solution



def parse_record(data_record):
    """
    parse the data record from a tfrecord file, typically pulled from an iterator,
    in this case a one_shot_iterator created from the dataset.
    """
    feature = {'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
               'image/object/class/label': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
               'image/object/bbox/xmin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
               'image/object/bbox/ymin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
               'image/object/bbox/xmax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
               'image/object/bbox/ymax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
               'image/filename': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
               }
    return tf.io.parse_single_example(data_record, feature)


if __name__ == '__main__':
class_labels =  {"dog" : 1}

data_paths = [r"train.record-00000-of-00010"]
all_images = list()

for file_path in data_paths:

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([file_path])
    record_iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)
    num_records = dataset.reduce(np.int64(0), lambda x, _: x + 1).numpy()

    for im_ind in range(num_records):

        #Parse and process example

        parsed_example = parse_record(record_iterator.get_next())

        fname = parsed_example['image/filename'].numpy()
        fname = fname.decode()
        if ".ipynb_checkpoints" in fname:
            continue
        all_images.append(fname)

print(all_images)
print(len(all_images))
```