# How do I extract the values from these tensors in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I need to get the filenames of the images in my dataset from the tensorflow shard records they were transformed into so that I can use the names to feed my neural network other features. I cannot form a list a head of time because of randomization. I need the names immediately before they are fed to the network.

I am using inception v3 running on tensorflow v1.14.
Each serialized example is parsed with this code, which I have edited to also return filename:

```
def parse_example_proto(example_serialized):
  """Parses an Example proto containing a training example of an image.

  The output of the build_image_data.py image preprocessing script is a dataset
  containing serialized Example protocol buffers. Each Example proto contains
  the following fields:

    image/height: 462
    image/width: 581
    image/colorspace: 'RGB'
    image/channels: 3
    image/class/label: 615
    image/class/synset: 'n03623198'
    image/class/text: 'knee pad'
    image/object/bbox/xmin: 0.1
    image/object/bbox/xmax: 0.9
    image/object/bbox/ymin: 0.2
    image/object/bbox/ymax: 0.6
    image/object/bbox/label: 615
    image/format: 'JPEG'
    image/filename: 'ILSVRC2012_val_00041207.JPEG'
    image/encoded: <JPEG encoded string>

  Args:
    example_serialized: scalar Tensor tf.string containing a serialized
      Example protocol buffer.

  Returns:
    image_buffer: Tensor tf.string containing the contents of a JPEG file.
    label: Tensor tf.int32 containing the label.
    bbox: 3-D float Tensor of bounding boxes arranged [1, num_boxes, coords]
      where each coordinate is [0, 1) and the coordinates are arranged as
      [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax].
    text: Tensor tf.string containing the human-readable label.
  """
  # Dense features in Example proto.
  if FLAGS.mode == '0_softmax':
    feature_map = {
        'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,
                                            default_value=''),
        'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], dtype=tf.int64,
                                                default_value=-1),
        'image/class/text': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,
                                               default_value=''),
        'image/filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,
                                               default_value=''),
    }
  elif FLAGS.mode == '1_sigmoid':
    Vdefault = [0]
    for kk in range(FLAGS.ClassNumber):
      Vdefault.append(0)
    feature_map = {
        'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,
                                            default_value=''),
        'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], dtype=tf.int64,
                                                default_value=-1),
        'image/class/text': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,
                                               default_value=''),
        'image/filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,
                                               default_value=''),
    }
  else:
    raise ValueError("You must set the mode option (to 0_softmax or 1_sigmoid for example)")

  sparse_float32 = tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32)
  # Sparse features in Example proto.
  feature_map.update(
      {k: sparse_float32 for k in ['image/object/bbox/xmin',
                                   'image/object/bbox/ymin',
                                   'image/object/bbox/xmax',
                                   'image/object/bbox/ymax']})

  features = tf.parse_single_example(example_serialized, feature_map)
  label = tf.cast(features['image/class/label'], dtype=tf.int32)

  xmin = tf.expand_dims(features['image/object/bbox/xmin'].values, 0)
  ymin = tf.expand_dims(features['image/object/bbox/ymin'].values, 0)
  xmax = tf.expand_dims(features['image/object/bbox/xmax'].values, 0)
  ymax = tf.expand_dims(features['image/object/bbox/ymax'].values, 0)

  # Note that we impose an ordering of (y, x) just to make life difficult.
  bbox = tf.concat(axis=0, values=[ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax])

  # Force the variable number of bounding boxes into the shape
  # [1, num_boxes, coords].
  bbox = tf.expand_dims(bbox, 0)
  bbox = tf.transpose(bbox, [0, 2, 1])

  return features['image/encoded'], label, bbox, features['image/filename']
```

This function is called in the code snippet. The inceptionv3 codebase has lots of parallel processing code which I don't understand but I am making due I think. However, I don't know how to interpret the output of `tf.train.batch_join`. Looking at the filenames output in the vscode debugger, it's a `<tf.Tensor 'batch_processing/batch_join:2' shape=(32,) dtype=string>`.

```
for thread_id in range(num_preprocess_threads):
      # Parse a serialized Example proto to extract the image and metadata.
      image_buffer, label_index, bbox, filename = parse_example_proto(
          example_serialized)
      image = image_preprocessing(image_buffer, bbox, train, thread_id)
      images_and_labels.append([image, label_index, filename])

    images, label_index_batch, filenames = tf.train.batch_join(
        images_and_labels,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        capacity=3 * num_preprocess_threads * batch_size)
```

When this returns I want to see what the values (filenames) in filenames. It appears that it should be a list and I should be able to index into it, but I can't seem to index into it, let alone get the filename for each one.

I've been able to get the filenames when I read the records directly using something like `parsed = _parse_function(raw_record)`
, `fname = parses['image/filename'].numpy()` but doesn't work here. I'm really flying at the seam of my pants with this haha.

Comment: What does _I can’t seem to index into it_ mean?

Comment: Depending on what I try, it gives me a different error.
When I do a for loop:
 Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn. 
When I turn on eager exectution with for loop:
RuntimeError: Input pipelines based on Queues are not supported when eager execution is enabled. Please use tf.data to ingest data into your model instead

I think am not somehow not creating a proper session

Comment: Do you solve your question? If not have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/60202093/5595995?