# Tensorflow - Extract string from Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to follow the "Load using tf.data" part of [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#load_using_tfdata). In the tutorial, they can get away with only working with string Tensors, however, I need to extract the string representation of the filename, as I need to look up extra data from a dictionary. I can't seem to extract the string part of a Tensor. I'm pretty sure the `.name` attribute of a Tensor should return the string, but I keep getting an error message saying `KeyError: 'strided_slice_1:0'` so somehow, the slicing is doing something weird?

I'm loading the dataset using:

```py
dataset_list = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(DATASET_DIR / "data/*"))
```

and then process it using:

```py
def process(t):
    return dataset.process_image_path(t, param_data, param_min_max)

dataset_labeled = dataset_list.map(
    process, 
    num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

where `param_data` and `param_min_max` are two dictionaries I've loaded that contains extra data that is needed to construct the label.

These are the three functions that I use to process the data Tensors (from my `dataset.py`):

```py
def process_image_path(image_path, param_data_file, param_max_min_file):
    label = path_to_label(image_path, param_data_file, param_max_min_file)
    img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    return (img, label)


def decode_img(img):
    """Converts an image to a 3D uint8 tensor"""
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    return img


def path_to_label(image_path, param_data_file, param_max_min_file):
    """Returns the NORMALIZED label (set of parameter values) of an image."""
    parts = tf.strings.split(image_path, os.path.sep)
    filename = parts[-1]  # Extract filename with extension
    filename = tf.strings.split(filename, ".")[0].name  # Extract filename
    param_data = param_data_file[filename]  # ERROR! .name above doesn't seem to return just the filename
    P = len(param_max_min_file)

    label = np.zeros(P)

    i = 0
    while i < P:
        param = param_max_min_file[i]
        umin = param["user_min"]
        umax = param["user_max"]
        sub_index = param["sub_index"]
        identifier = param["identifier"]
        node = param["node_name"]
        value = param_data[node][identifier]

        label[i] = _normalize(value[sub_index])
        i += 1

    return label
```

I have verified that `filename = tf.strings.split(filename, ".")[0]` in `path_to_label()` does return the correct Tensor, but I need it as a string. The whole thing is proving difficult to debug as well, as I can't access attributes when debugging (I get errors saying `AttributeError: Tensor.name is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` field is a name for the tensor itself, not the content of the tensor.

To do a regular python dictionary lookup, wrap your parsing function in `tf.py_func`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

d = {"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 10}
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["a", "b", "c"])

def parse(s):
  return s, d[s]
dataset = dataset.map(lambda s: tf.py_func(parse, [s], (tf.string, tf.int64)))

for element in dataset:
  print(element[1].numpy()) # prints 1, 3, 10
```

Comment: Thank you, but I decided that I should probably keep everything as tensors. So now I'm outputting the values as a CSV file instead! I can read this file using `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset` and then zip this file with the image dataset and then map them as tuples.

Comment: In the `tf` version `2.7.0` the `tf.py_func` had to change to `tf.py_function`

Comment: Besides what @nipun said, you don't need the second line as eager execution is enabled by default in Tensorflow 2